# Using package hooks with hyperref to avoid package conflicts

Tags: hyperref, lthooks

By now only a small number of packages, need to be loaded after `hyperref`. Consider the code below, that creates a `clist` with such packages `algorithm`,1`algorithmic`,`arydshln` and `chappg`. So far the code works fine, loading these packages after `hyperref`. The code uses `doc`, which uses `hypdoc` with a lot of re-definitions etc.
The code uses `\disable@package@load` with two arguments, the first is the package name and the second, as per the manual can be used to add a message. However it fails using  **\wlog**, which seems to be ignored (it looks that the second argument is gobbled). How can I fix this? It has this issue either when using a map or not. the code is intended to be loaded by a class.

```
%\listfiles
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\clist_set:Nn\hyperconflicts{algorithm,algorithmic,arydshln, chappg}
\clist_map_inline:Nn\hyperconflicts{
  \disable@package@load {#1}{\wlog{CONFLICTED~#1~XXXX}\ERROR} %does not work
  \AddToHook{package/hyperref/after}{
    \reenable@package@load{#1}
    \usepackage{#1}
  }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypdoc}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\section{algorithm and algorithmic packages}
\IfPackageLoadedTF{algorithm}{T}{F}

\begin{algorithmic} \WHILE{some condition holds} \STATE carry out some processing \ENDWHILE \end{algorithmic}

\section{the arydshln package}
\begin{tabular}{|l::c:r|}\hline
A&B&C\\\hdashline
AAA&BBB&CCC\\\cdashline{1-2}
\multicolumn{2}{|l:}{AB}&C\\\hdashline\hdashline
\end{tabular}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Two}
\section{Two-One}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe my expectations are mistaken, but it works as I'd expect. If I add `\usepackage{algorithm}` I get an error. If I remove `\ERROR`, I get a message in the log saying the package conflicts and has been disabled. `algorithm` is then loaded later, after `hyperref`.

Comment: @cfr Thanks.  It works as advertized if I take the `disable@package@load`  outside the loop.  The `\ERROR` I added it so it would stop and I could see what was happening. I think it is my own expectations that were wrong.

Comment: you want the disable to be in the loop but you need to add `\usepackage{arydshln}` after that and before loading hyperref (it would have been clearer if you had posted an example in a form that had wrong load order so was expected to do something, here you don't load any of the listed packages)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. As long as the package is in the `clist`, there is no way to get the log, as the hook system takes care of it.  I tried hard:) It seems I cannot use the `disable@package@load ` to  log, easy though to do my own logging.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this works as you suggested  `\clist_map_inline:Nn\hyperconflicts{
  \disable@package@load{#1}{\wlog{CONFLICTED~#1~XXXX}} %does not work
  \usepackage{algorithm}
  \AddToHook{package/hyperref/after}{
    \reenable@package@load{#1}
    \usepackage{#1}
  }
}`